# Python のマイナーバージョンの変更点を知りたい

Tags: python

Python 3.3 から Python 3.7.13 までのアップデートで重大な変更点はありますか？
いくつか教えてください。

Answer (score 3):

「重大な変更点」は何に注目してるかによって異なるので, 以下のリンクから必要とする項目調べるとよいかもです

- 3.3 と比較した Python 3.4 の新機能: [What's New In Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/whatsnew/3.4.html)
- 3.4 と比較した Python 3.5 の新機能: [What's New In Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/whatsnew/3.5.html)
- 3.5 と比較した Python 3.6 の新機能: [What's New In Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/whatsnew/3.6.html)
- 3.6 と比較した Python 3.7 の新機能: [What's New In Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/whatsnew/3.7.html)

おおよそ次のような項目が載ってます

- 新たな文法機能:
- 後方非互換な文法の変更:
- 新たなライブラリモジュール:
- 新たな組み込み機能:
- CPython の実装の改善:
- 標準ライブラリーの顕著な改善
- セキュリティの改善:

他に Python 3.7.10 final までの変更履歴もあるので, 参考に

- https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/whatsnew/changelog.html

Comment: ドキュメントの英語版のページだと 3.7.13 final までの変更履歴も見えるようですね。

Comment: そのようですね。/ja/3.8/whatsnew/changelog.html にも 3.7.xxの変更履歴は載っていないようなので 3.7.10〜3.7.13は 英語版見るしかなさそう